# use vba/vbs to open xlsx with password and save into a new xlsx

Tags: vba, vbscript

Have a use case. There is a password-encrypted xlsx. The password is for reading the workbook only, and I cannot make any edit or remove the password.

I need an xlsx without password so downstream processing can take the info from there. What I'm thinking is to open a new workbook and save the data there, but it always got stuck at the step where it's trying to open the encrypted workbook. Any idea?

```
Sub OpenXlsx()
set objExcel = Create.Object("Excel.Application")
path = "c:/myfilepath.xlsx"
newpath = "c:/12myfilepath.xlsx"
' next line Not Working. It's able to open the 
' excel, but Excel is still stuck at the screen 
' to enter password, and 'excel is waiting for another 
' application to complete an ole action'
set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, Password = "123")
set wb1 = objExcel.Wookbooks.Add()

wb.Sheets(1).cells.copy
wb1.Sheets(1).cells.paste PasteSpecial:=xlPasteValues
wb1.SaveAs(newpath)
wb.Close
wb1.Close
objExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: `Password := "123"`

Answer (score 1):

Since the extension is xlsx it's the Microsoft Excel Open XML Format. That is essentially a .zip file. Try this:

1. Copy the original file to a new folder so you don't tamper the original
2. Rename the file to a .zip extension
3. Extract the content with winzip or the like
4. In the extracted content, open **xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml** as a text file with notepad or the like
5. Search for **<sheetProtection**
6. Remove all from **<sheetProtection** to and including the terminating **/>** and save.
7. Save the content as a .zip
8. Rename to .xlsx
9. Open the file. Password should be gone.

Excel 2016 file **passworded.xlsx** renamed as **passworded.zip** opened in WinZip:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just curious - given you what mentioned on the zip part, is there a python package that is able to perform this? My downstream processing is able to integrate python code so i don't have to figure out this step in VBS. Thanks!

Comment: I never use python. If you find my answer useful, you might accept it by doing so.

Comment: I tried your answer, but didn't see xl folder. Instead, i only see a folder 'DataSpaces' and 3 files 'EncryptionInfo' 'EncryptedPackage' and 'DocumentSummaryInformation'. Any idea?

Comment: What's the Excel version?

Comment: Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2016. Tried on different files and saw the same structure mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

msoffcrypto is the way to go. Just tested it and it's able to open pwd encrypted xlsx without dependency on pywin32 or any package that makes Win32 COM API call.

https://pypi.org/project/msoffcrypto-tool/